# Why do I have to "invalidate" my window to avoid disappearing fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I had a fully functional app with three tabs switching between three fragments. Then I made some quite large changes to the back-end, but nothing that I think could interfere with the GUI. But it did -- the fragments now tend to disappear.

The tabs are changed like this:

```
mActiveFragment = null;
switch (index) {
    case 0:
        mActiveFragment = new TabOneFragment();
        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("One");
        break;
    case 1:
        mActiveFragment = new TabTwoFragment();
        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Two");
        break;
    case 2:
        mActiveFragment = new TabThreeFragment();
        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Three");
        break;
}

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.pnlTabContent, mActiveFragment).commit();
```

And this worked just fine before I made my seemingly unrelated changes. Now, it works for a couple of times, and then the fragment container stays empty until I close and reopen the activity.

- When the fragments disappear, the rightmost button in my Action bar also disappears, and no of the action bar buttons seems to work.
- The number of times it works seems to be random (but low, usually two or three tab changes).
- No exceptions are thrown, and I can see nothing of interest in logcat (only regular log messages from my app).
- The fragments are never null, and their onActivityCreated, onCreateView, and onAttach methods are executed.
- The fragment container (pnlTabContent) never disappears (I changed the background color to red, to verify).
- Views in the fragments returns true on isShown, which should indicate that no parent views have ther visibility set to GONE or INVISIBLE. I checked the entire code base anyway, and found no code changing the visibility of parent containers.
- They just don't appear.

**Now, I have found that the tab change always works if I add this line after the tab change:**

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_CHANGED);
```

Or any other flag for that matter. So it seems I now need to refresh the window to keep the fragments from disappearing.

Any ideas on why this happened? I know it will be difficult to debug without seeing what changes I did, but as they are pretty large, and distributed over 20 different files, I don't think there is any point in sharing them. So I'm looking for general ideas to what can be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, of course, after working with this issue for five hours, I manage to fix it right after posting the question here.

It turned out one of my changes was a bugfix to fix a `CalledFromWrongThreadException` when calling `notifyDataSetChanged` on one of my ArrayAdapters. Since this class didn't have access to any Activity, I used a handler to run it on the UI thread:

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
```

And for some reason, this did something to my activity. I don't know much about handlers, but I guess I created some kind of inconsistency. I changed the code, and ran it from an actual activity's runOnUIThread(), and everything now works again.